# How do I configure Kalman Filter and define a state vector to model a projectile motion correctly?

Tags: computer-vision, tracking, kalman-filter, projectile

I am experimenting with Kalman filter implementation of Matlab. I wish to model the motion of a ball tossed up by a child in the air using Kalman filter. I have manually annotated the position of the ball in the image frames to use as measurements (ground truth values) for initializing and updating the kalman filter. I have defined the state to be a 6-dimensional vector as follows:

[X Vx Ax Y Vx Ay]

X - x coordinate Vx - velocity in x coordinate Ax - acceleration in x coordinate Y - x coordinate Vy - velocity in x coordinate Ay - acceleration in x coordinate

Kalman filter is configured using the following call:

kalmanFilter = myConfigureKalmanFilter('ConstantAcceleration',centroid, [0.5 0.5 0.5]*1e2, [25, 10, 10], 25);

where centroid corresponds to the (X,Y) ground truth value of first frame (985 as per excel document)

The Prediction values (of frames 986 onwards) are generated using the following call:

[predictedCentroid, state] = predict(kalmanFilter);

The kalman filter is updated using the following call with the ground truth value corresponding to the frames (986 onwards):

correct(kalmanFilter, centroid);

[image]

The result of this experiment is shown in the figure.

Problem : The values of Ay are observed to not be constant and seem to be increasing and decreasing in an irregular fashion. Since this is a case of projectile motion with gravity imparting constant acceleration in the y direction, these values should not drift much which is not the case.

Note: These values are in pixel coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem here is that the ball is moving in a 3D space, but you are tracking the 2D projection of its motion. Also, even in the 3D space the acceleration is not really constant because of air resistance.

Having said that, constant acceleration is probably still be best motion model in this case. I would try increasing the process noise covariance to account for the fact that the motion model is not quite right.

You may also want to do some fine tuning of the covariance. For example, your estimate of the acceleration is probably more noisy than that of the position.

**Edit:**

Lens distortion is a separate problem. If you can correct for it, that's always a good thing. But what I was talking about is the fact that the ball moves in 3D, but the video you are looking at shows a 2D projection of that motion.

It the real 3D world you have a constant acceleration due to gravity pointing down, and the ball's trajectory is a parabola in 3D. When you look at the video of the ball moving, its trajectory is a 2D projection of that parabola, which may be skewed, depending on the camera angle. As a result, this 2D trajectory may not have a constant acceleration.

Consider the extreme case. The ball is thrown across the field. The camera is positioned above the field looking straight down. In 3D the ball is actually flying in a parabola, first slowing down, then speeding back up until it hits the ground, because of the constant acceleration pointing down. But to the camera above, it will look like the ball is moving in a straight line, first accelerating and then decelerating. In the video there is no third dimension, so instead of a constant downward acceleration you will observe a variable acceleration along the trajectory.

The only way this will work, is if your image plane is parallel to the plane of the ball's motion. Then the 3D parabolic trajectory will project onto the image as a 2D parabola, and the constant acceleration will point down along the Y axis.

Comment: By "tracking the 2D projection" do you mean to say that I should consider undistorting the images before processing because currently I am using distorted images and there is barrel distortion to a great extent.

Comment: I agree with you that the parabolic curve would be skewed. But if we assume a constant angle between the plane of motion of ball and the camera with relative tilt confined to only one direction, then it would imply that acceleration should still remain constant in y direction as it is a matter of taking component of g in the direction of motion of the ball which is a constant number.